# My window control buttons sometimes disappear after suspend

Tags: suspend, themes, 16.04

My close / maximize / minimize buttons sometimes disappears, as well as my top menu after my system comes back from sleep.

It goes is transparent and not black (ambience theme).  How can I fix this? Is it a Kernel or graphic problem?

My notebook is a ProBook 4520s and I use Intel HD Graphics

Comment: Press Alt+F2 then press r then enter. Does that fix it?

Comment: Hi Tim, nothing happened when I press Alt+F2. The command unity --reset temporary fix the problem, but they come back if I suspend again or passed a few hours.

Comment: The problem persist. Anyone can help me not going back to Windows?